# Setting up Rate limit logic for telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Hey can someone suggest me how to make users wait for certain time before doing the same task in telegram bot means if they download an image by url they have to wait for next one minute to do the same?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to present?

Comment: I tried to create a dictionary and append the user id to it after 1 minute I deleted the entry after certain time but it's not working correctly and I am also little confused about it so I asked if anyone could improve it.